# How to load json in main method Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I'm trying to load a json file into my main() app method.
Can you tell me if this is possible? I've tryed File and rootBundle but it seems that Assets' folder are not ready yet.

here is my code:

ASSETS

```
  assets:
    - assets/settings/settings.json
```

MAIN METHOD

```
void main() async {
    final file = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/settings/settings.json');
      final data = jsonDecode(file);
      Settings settings = Get.put(Settings.fromJson(data), permanent: true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more info? For instance, your pubspec.yaml file. Are you having any error at all? What is the output when you try to print your variable 'data'?

Comment: i prefer doing inside MyApp() initState

Comment: * I'm using the getx package to make instances https://pub.dev/packages/get

* The error Im having is " Null check operator used on a null value
", this happens when rootBundle is executed.

What I'm trying to do is load my settings.json before the whole app stars, something like NetCore load appsettings.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution using FutureBuilder

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  _load() async {
    final file = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/j.json');
    final data = await jsonDecode(file);
    print(data.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _load(),
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return !snapshot.hasData
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                  )),
                )
              : MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text("Body"),

        // MaxWidthButton(),
      ),
    );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried the initState and It didn't work, instead of load on my initState method I tried calling my method in a FutureBuilder and that works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I dont seems it is, instead try on `MyApp` and make it `statefullWidget`

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _load();
  }

  _load() async {
    final file = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/j.json');
    final data = await jsonDecode(file);
    print(data.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text("Body"),

        // MaxWidthButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, throws same error "Null check operator used on a null value"

Comment: check updated answer , if you find any error ,please share?